# how to fix undefined index $user = $_GET['user'];

Tags: php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include("global.php");

$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);

$user = $_GET['user'];
//$customer = $_GET['customer'];
$querystring = "";
$querystring = "SELECT email, password, firstname, lastname from user ";
$result = $conn->query($querystring);



$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"email":"'  . $rs["email"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"password":"'  . $rs["password"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"firstname":"'   . $rs["firstname"] . '",';   
    $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"]. '"}';
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

This is the PHP code in the database and need to use get method. the error shows undefined index : `$user = $_GET['user'];` when I run it shows this error. How to fix it?

Comment: Clear this line-> $user = $_GET['user']; ..You don't us of $user variable.

Comment: Test using isset($_GET['user']) before using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue by add isset in $_GET['user'] and check its empty or not

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include("global.php");

$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);

if( isset($_GET['user']) && $_GET['user']!='' ){
    $user = $_GET['user'];
}else{
    $user='';
}
//$customer = $_GET['customer'];
$querystring = "";
$querystring = "SELECT email, password, firstname, lastname from user ";
$result = $conn->query($querystring);

    enter code here

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"email":"'  . $rs["email"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"password":"'  . $rs["password"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"firstname":"'   . $rs["firstname"] . '",';   
    $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"]. '"}';
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Another way is that you can add @ in front of $_GET['user']

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include("global.php");

$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);

@$user = $_GET['user'];

//$customer = $_GET['customer'];
$querystring = "";
$querystring = "SELECT email, password, firstname, lastname from user ";
$result = $conn->query($querystring);

    enter code here

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"email":"'  . $rs["email"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"password":"'  . $rs["password"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"firstname":"'   . $rs["firstname"] . '",';   
    $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"]. '"}';
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the IF condition in below code you can check it. By adding this condition you are able to solve the undefine index issue

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include("global.php");

$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
if(!isset($_GET['user']) && empty($_GET['user']))
return false;// this will send back if data or index is not found and also solve the undefine index problem
$user = $_GET['user'];
//$customer = $_GET['customer'];
$querystring = "";
$querystring = "SELECT email, password, firstname, lastname from user ";
$result = $conn->query($querystring);



$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"email":"'  . $rs["email"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"password":"'  . $rs["password"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"firstname":"'   . $rs["firstname"] . '",';   
    $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"]. '"}';
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Comment: after i add the if statement. it return empty. nothing show.

Comment: means you are not getting any value in GET. Can you print $_GET and paste the print string here so i can check

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to check if an array's index is undefined. The example below uses two methods: `isset` and `empty`.

The call to `isset` returns true if the array has the specified key.

The call to `empty` will return true if the value for the specified index is "empty" (null, empty string, zero, empty array, etc...) or if the specified key does not exist.

```
    <?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    include("global.php");

    $conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);

    $user = isset($_GET['user'])&&!empty($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : NULL;
    //$customer = $_GET['customer'];
    $querystring = "";
    $querystring = "SELECT email, password, firstname, lastname from user ";
    $result = $conn->query($querystring);



    $outp = "[";
    while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
        $outp .= '{"email":"'  . $rs["email"] . '",';
        $outp .= '"password":"'  . $rs["password"] . '",';
        $outp .= '"firstname":"'   . $rs["firstname"] . '",';   
        $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"]. '"}';
    }
    $outp .="]";

    $conn->close();

    echo($outp);
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?